# Nielsen & Chuang, Exercise 2.14 — Proof of anti-linearity of Hermitian conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hilbert-spaces

How can I prove that the adjoint operation/ Hermitian conjugate in anti-linear, i.e.,

$$ \left( \sum_{i} a_i A_i \right)^\dagger = \sum_{i} a_i^* A_i^\dagger$$

where $A$ is any linear operator on a Hilbert space $V$.

---

The problem is from [Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information) Exercise 2.14, this is not my homework, just doing it for pleasure.

Comment: Which edition??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the R.H.S

$\sum_{i} a_i^* A_i^\dagger = (a_1 A_1)^\dagger + (a_2 A_2)^\dagger + ....+ (a_n A_n)^\dagger$

$= \sum_{i} (a_i A_i)^\dagger$

On the L.H.S

We know that $(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T$ and $(a+b)^* = a^* + b^*$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

hence $(\sum_{i} a_i A_i)^\dagger = \sum_{i} (a_i A_i)^\dagger$

I have mentioned the answer in my [blog](http://wobblybit.com/nielsenchuang/exercise-2-14/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Nielsen and Chuang's definition of the Hermitian conjugate directly, along with the inner product's linearity in the second argument and conjugate-linearity in the first argument (Exercise 2.6).

Let $|v\rangle$ and $|w\rangle$ be vectors in some Hilbert space $V$, using the definition $(|v\rangle,A|w\rangle) = (A^\dagger|v\rangle,|w\rangle)$, where $(.,.)$ denotes inner product:

$(|v\rangle, \sum_ia_iA_i|w_i\rangle)$

$ = \sum_ia_i(|v\rangle, A_i|w_i\rangle)$ by 2nd argument linearity of inner product

$ = \sum_ia_i(A_i^\dagger|v_i\rangle, |w\rangle)$ by definition of Hermitian conjugate

$ = (\sum_ia_i^*A_i^\dagger|v_i\rangle, |w\rangle)$ by 1st argument conjugate-linearity of inner product

$\Rightarrow (\sum_ia_iA_i)^\dagger = \sum_ia_i^*A_i^\dagger$ by definition of Hermitian conjugate

Comment: The last step is what we are exactly trying to prove. It is not very clear how you are implying it in the last step. Its just a matter of tweaking the summations a bit, but other than that its fine.

Comment: Since $(|v\rangle, \sum_ia_iA_i|w_i\rangle)$ must equal $((\sum_ia_iA_i)^\dagger|v_i\rangle, |w\rangle)$, and we just showed that it is equal to $(\sum_ia_i^*A_i^\dagger|v_i\rangle, |w\rangle)$ also, then the two operators $(\sum_ia_iA_i)^\dagger$ and $\sum_ia_i^*A_i^\dagger$ must be the same.